# Class not found exception with byte buddy Java agent

Tags: javaagents, byte-buddy

I'm trying to use byte Buddy with bigger application. My point for now is just to log something out on method enter/exit with @Advice. My agent attach to application correctly and is built. In logs I can also see that the transformation of pointed class is also done. Problem is when I'm sending request on needed RestEndpoint and method is called I get error :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/agent/MyAdviser

at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:391)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
```

My agent  :

```
LOG.info("Before Agent Builder build !!!");
          new AgentBuilder.Default()
                  .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
                    .type(is(MyClassToCatch.class))
                  .transform(
                        new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                        .include(MyAgent.class.getClassLoader())
                        .advice(ElementMatchers.any(), MyAdviser.class.getName())
                )
                .installOn(inst);
```

And MyAdviser.class is :

```
public class MyAdviser {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAdviser.class);

@Advice.OnMethodEnter
public static void onEnterExit() {
    LOG.info("INTERCEPTED BBB <<<>>> BBB");
}
```

Is the problem connected to classloader somehow ?
BR,

**Rafael's solution helped.**

**EDIT**: I've tried also to intercept a method, and just call it without any changes but I've ended with an error like this :

```
com.agent.DiscoveryAgent - On Error of : MyClassToCatch       None of [net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@7815f1c, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@a193f70f, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@d6fdc355, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@66e2275b, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@19cb065f, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@4fc13971, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@aea74e0e, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@2ac04890, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@f5eef57c, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@e1b04a0f, net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.TargetMethodAnnotationDrivenBinder$Record@f0de1c86] allows for delegation from public javax.ws.rs.core.Response MyClassToCatch.someMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the advice class is copied into the target class. This means, that it needs to be able to resolve the `MyAdviser` class. If this is not possible, you have to:

1. Define the `Logger` as a field on the transformed class via `defineField` and the `@FieldValue` annotation.
2. Read the logger dynamically from within the advice and reference another class that is visible as the log root.

Comment: Hi Rafael ! Thanks for helping, I finally did it and something logged out, as expected.